# Memory error calculating Pearson correlation on huge dask.dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe, pearson

I have a huge dataset (9M rows * 125 cols) and I am trying to find a way to calculate the Pearson correlation for a variable vs rest. I receive memory error for this task. I tried dask as a solution as suggested in [enter link description here][1] but it did not work.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code as text. Please also include a reproducible example, such that viewers can copy and paste your code and reproduce your error.

Comment: Feel free to ask a question about a specific dask issue! Dask ***does*** work, but it can be tricky to learn how to use it correctly. If you don’t post your code though we can’t help. See the guide to [ask] and especially [mre]